# The origin of the word 'aphotic'

Tags: word-request

For example, *hyperbolic* is a word for a something related to *hyperbole*. There is a word that's an adjective or a noun for these type of words and I cannot find one for this one. Also, *parabola* > *parabolic*. I was thinking of *aphosis* but that is not a word, I think.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is word golf. If you need a word to help you express a specific meaning, we can help, but I don't think this sort of word puzzle is useful to EFL learners. If the question can be edited to make it clearer how this relates to learning practical English, I will retract my close vote. This may be on-topic at [English.se].

Comment: This question has been moved to here from that website. Should I repost it there?

Comment: If it was moved, closing it here would have rejected the migration and sent it back. Was there a reason given why it was closed on [English.se]? Reposting isn't the right way to go about it - editing the question to address the reasons why it was closed is.

Answer (score 1):

The word itself is derived from Greek: *a* means 'no' and *photos* means 'light'. That more or less fits with its [meaning](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aphotic):

> being the deep zone of an ocean or lake receiving too little light to permit photosynthesis

Not all adjectives in English have a corresponding noun which is in common use.

Comment: You've failed to answer the question. The answer would be words that have been derived from aphotic or have derived from aphotic. If only aphoticity or aphoticness were words; It may have been easier. I'm aware of what you're saying and I'm aware of the definition.

Comment: @FredCaston I think he does answer it - there is no noun derivative or parent. While I agree that a parabola is parabolic, that does mean that all adjectives have a direct noun equivalent. In the case of aphotic, I think the closest you'll find is the compound aphotic-zone

Comment: Perhaps, it is.